# How informal is "I am fond of"?

Tags: formality, politeness

As said in the title how informal is "I am fond of", can I start a cold-email to a design studio like I am fond of your works or designs?

Comment: Formality (especially in borderline cases) is a matter of opinion. However, are you sure that *fond,* with all its [connotations of affection](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fond), is really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fond" implies you're familiar with and like or appreciate the work *personally*, outside of any commercial or business context under which you're contacting them.

If that's **true**, then I don't see any problem mentioning it; but if it's not then it's ill-advised to say so. The truth may well out at some point and you'll look like you were being purposely deceptive for some gain.

Comment: I really like their work personally but I think it's better to leave it out because the reason I'm contacting them is for business purposes.. (me being a client)

Comment: I guess "impressed by" would work better, if you would like to say something positive